# Postgres function to show new column values after update as JSON

Tags: json, postgresql, plpgsql, jsonb, postgresql-9.5

I am trying to write a postgres function for `AFTER UPDATE` trigger that creates a JSON object with column names and their updated values for only the columns that changed. I am trying to create a generalized function that I can use for any table hence using `Record` as function argument. The `old` and `new` are coming from trigger's `OLD` and `NEW` variables. The end goal is to save the returned JSON into a JSON field in an audit table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION row_updates(old RECORD, new RECORD) RETURNS JSON AS
$$
DECLARE
    updates JSON;
BEGIN
    WITH columns AS (
        SELECT json_object_keys(row_to_json(new)) "column"
    )
    SELECT
        json_object_agg("column", new_value) INTO updates
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            "column",
            (row_to_json(new)->"column" #>> '{}') as new_value,
            (row_to_json(old)->"column" #>> '{}') as old_value
        FROM
            columns
    ) changes
    WHERE 
        new_value IS DISTINCT FROM old_value;

    RETURN updates;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION audit_change() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
DECLARE
    updates JSON;
BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
        raise NOTICE 'Logging insert on relation (%.%) %', TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_TABLE_NAME;

        RETURN NEW;
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
        updates := row_updates(OLD, NEW)
        raise NOTICE 'Logging update on relation (%.%) %', TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_TABLE_NAME, updates;
        RETURN NEW;
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
        raise NOTICE 'Logging delete on relation (%.%) %', TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_TABLE_NAME;
        RETURN OLD;
    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I am getting this error:
`ERROR:  PL/pgSQL functions cannot accept type record`.

Is there a better way of accomplishing this? Obviously I want to do it in non trigger function so I can reuse it in different triggers for different tables. Also I may want to adapt it for `AFTER INSERT` and `AFTER DELETE` triggers if possible so I don't want to branch off `TG_OP` in trigger function and repeat the logic shown in SQL above.

End goal:

```
=> select * from org_user;

 id | org_id | user_id 
----+--------+---------
  1 |      1 |       1
 23 |      1 |       3

=> update org_user set org_id=3, user_id = 4 where id = 23; 

-- trigger creates following row in audit table

 id | relation  | record_id | updates 
----+-----------+-----------+--------------
  1 |  org_user |     23    | {'org_id': 3, 'user_id': 4}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a function that compares two `JSONB` values:

```
create or replace function jsonb_diff(jsonb, jsonb)
returns jsonb language sql immutable as $$
    select jsonb_object_agg(n.key, n.value)
    from jsonb_each($1) o
    join jsonb_each($2) n on o.key = n.key
    where o.value <> n.value;
$$;
```

and use it in your trigger function:

```
    updates := jsonb_diff(to_jsonb(OLD), to_jsonb(NEW));
    raise NOTICE 'Logging update on relation (%.%) %', TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_TABLE_NAME, updates;
    RETURN NEW;
```

By the way, in Postgres 11+ you can use function arguments of the `record` type.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please provide a reference for `record` type being allowed as function arguments in Postgres 11+?

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot find an official note about it. You can check this by comparing [DbFiddle-10](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=746eab04dbe7dff52827a2ab31b245a1) and [DbFiddle-11.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=746eab04dbe7dff52827a2ab31b245a1)